# print numbers that are in both arrays

Tags: c, arrays, loops

I am new to C programming. I am trying to figure out how to compare 2 arrays and print out which numbers are being repeated in both of them.
This is my code:

```
const int SIZE = 5;
int firstArray[SIZE];
int secondArray[SIZE];
int i,j;

for(i=0; i<SIZE; ++i) {
    printf("enter a number: ");
    scanf("%d", &firstArray[i]);
}

for(i=0; i<SIZE; ++i) {
    printf("%d, ", firstArray[i]);
}
printf("into array 1\n");
for(j=0; j<SIZE; ++j) {
    printf("enter a number: ");
    scanf("%d", &secondArray[j]);
}

for(j=0; j<SIZE; ++j){
    printf("%d, ", secondArray[j]);
}
printf("into array 2\n");

for (i = 0; i<SIZE; ++i){
    for(j=i+1; j<SIZE; ++j){
        if(firstArray[i] == secondArray[j]){
            printf("%d", firstArray[i]);

    }
}
```

Example input:

```
array 1: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
array 2: 3, 4, 5, 6, 7
```

Expected output:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5 into array 1
3, 4, 5, 6, 7 into array 2
3 has been entered in both array
4 has been entered in both array
5 has been entered in both array
```

My code only lets me do the "into array" output. How do i achieve:

```
3 has been entered in both array
4 has been entered in both array
5 has been entered in both array
```

Comment: For each number in array 1, check if it is also in array 2 and if yes then print "x has been entered in both arrays"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your final loop to:

```
for (i = 0; i<SIZE; ++i)
{
    for(j = 0; j<SIZE; ++j)
    {
        if(firstArray[i] == secondArray[j])
            printf("%d has been entered in both array\n", firstArray[i]);

    }
}
```

Note: this code will repeat message (e.g. `4 has been entered in both array`) more than one time if 4 is present in at least one array more than 1 time.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (i = 0; i<SIZE; ++i){
   for(j = 0; j<SIZE; ++j){
     if(firstArray[i] == secondArray[j]){
          printf("%d has been entered in both array\n", firstArray[i]);
     }
   }
}
```

Here, in second loop you require, you need to change`j=i+1` to `j=0`, since you need to check for all values in both the arrays. Also, modify the `printf` statement to match your expected output.

Ideone link: http://ideone.com/YthNkx

Answer (score 1):

Try this for your last part:

```
for (i = 0; i<SIZE; ++i){
    for(j=0; j<SIZE; ++j){
        if(firstArray[i] == secondArray[j]){
            printf("%d", firstArray[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

You have to compare every number in the first array with every number in the second array. Hope it helps!